# spring boot rest download docx

Tags: spring, rest, file, kotlin, docx

I'm trying to download docx file but encoding goes wrong

```
@GetMapping(value = ["/get-file"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE])
@ResponseBody
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun getFile(): ByteArray {
    val file = File("somePath\\data.docx")
    val fis = FileInputStream(file)
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(fis)
}
```

what can i do with this?

> PKEi#P[Content_Types].xmlŖ�N�0E%�5. !����$��ֵ'���=���L�6B�i�b9��s��I���5�+���+�q>d8�v��=Mn�,�(��;(���r<�|T3��b����Q�����
>   )�V ݆��|3�'����!8`]��G�P����}^�.��*��@��N�,�L�s]�#2��杪��!52�G�������Ӿ��Gh�,����Ҕ\."z�l�C c@
>   K��NX*�;��6����P�L�T�dn�9��S��h��W`m<�j�|P�+!Fjbk�N�B�o��w��t�ㆭhVjR��jM���f�NNA�}�v���E��?�&��҈��bB�mB��m���i�`w~�&p;�@����""�zq��E���&��!�~�z����^�v�L����
>   �7?|�OPK�<�.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media type of docx is:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Comment: Right, just change your first line as  @GetMapping(value = ["/get-file"], produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")